# Using multipolygon shape layers in profile tool

Tags: shapefile, qgis-plugins, rasterization, profile, multi-polygon

I am working with QGIS for some time. The profile tool is indeed very useful to visualize the 3D problems. My problem now is associated with this tool.

I have a multi polygon shape layer which I assigned z levels by set z option in processing tool hence I believe z levels are assigned to the vertices of the multi polygons I have. I wanted to use this shape layer to plot a cross-section by using the profile tool however got an error as "unprofilable layer" or such. It is understandable since this layer is not a surface or a point data neither a raster. I cannot export this layer as DXF and turn it into a surface since I need the attributes assigned to these multipolygons for my project.

Is there any method so that I can transform this multipolygon shape layer into a kind of surface and/or raster or something else which I can both use it in the profile tool and also keep the attributes assigned?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interpolation with the multipolygon layer to generate a raster. Just need to set to interpolate Z coordinates.

For instance, with TIN interpolation tool:

[image: 1]

Also you can clip the raster with the multipolygon features, this is a test result with one feature which have two parts. The vertices were extracted to label their Z coordinate:

[image: 2]